# How do I export clip as video?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

I'm brand new to Blender. Had used KDenlive for video editing a couple times, but it wouldn't handle the large file (30 minutes) I'm working with now. I keep web-searching & keep finding adjacent things or old answers to different versions of Blender.

So I have the 30 minute video. I deleted the first minute. I cut out a 2-3 minute section, and I want to export that section as a `.mp4` or... webm or whatever is recommended nowadays.

[image: Video editor screen]

So I just keep poking around and getting overwhelmed. What/where do I click to export this first little section to video? (and I assume it would be similar for exporting the full thing as a video file?)

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.se. Please spend more time on basic [research](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=export%20video).

Comment: Oh golly. I did. Looked at the same stuff like 10 different times. Took a break & came back & i think I found it now. There's just so many controls I can't make sense of what's even there.

Comment: For the future: [output tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcoIk.png)

Comment: I chose the 'ffmpeg' file format, webm container, FLAC audio, and set the output director to `~/Videos/blender`. Also set the frame start=0 & frameend=4871. But I can't find the button to actually.. save it

Comment: This is called "rendering". Try to search for that term.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/animation.html  `6.) Save your blend-file.` - done
`7) Press the big *Animation* button.` - can't find the "big animation button"

Comment: Here are lots of screenshots for the whole process https://generallyplayful.com/hints/rendering-in-blender-2-8/

Comment: Just in case. [Rendering Screenshot](https://generallyplayful.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/render.png)

Comment: @Leander, that looks like what I needed. thank you much.

Comment: I got it! :D Once I knew the right buttons to click, I was able to figure out (because of an error message at the bottom) that there were codec-related problems. Then I just... poked around at different codec options. Ended FFMPEG file format,  MPE4 container, H.264 Video codec, and Vorbis Audio Codec, and it all is working.